# Как сделать скриншот с помощью горячих клавиш при свернутом окне, используя PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, клавиатура, скриншот

У меня есть был готовый скрипт, который по нажатию клавиши делает скриншот по типу *lightshot*.
И мне надо, чтобы можно было делать скриншот используя горячие клавиши, и не обязательно открывая окно.

Я пробовал использовать метод `.activateSnipping()`, но он срабатывает только когда ты работаешь с окном программы (когда окно программы свёрнуто или не активно, не работает).

Я пытался использовать модуль `keyboard`, в сочетании c `Threading`, но программа отказывается работать.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PIL import ImageGrab
import threading
import keyboard as keyb

class SnippingWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SnippingWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.outsideSquareColor = "red"
        self.squareThickness = 2

        self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint() 
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start_point = event.pos()
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        r = QtCore.QRect(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        self.hide()
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=r.getCoords())
        img.save("testpic/testImage.png")
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        self.closed.emit()
        self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        trans = QtGui.QColor(22, 100, 233)
        r = QtCore.QRectF(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        trans.setAlphaF(0.2)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        outer = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        outer.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()))
        inner = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        inner.addRect(r)
        r_path = outer - inner
        qp.drawPath(r_path)
        qp.setPen(
            QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(self.outsideSquareColor), self.squareThickness)
        )
        trans.setAlphaF(0)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        qp.drawRect(r)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Делать скриншот')
        self.button.setShortcut('Ctrl+7')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.activateSnipping)
        
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 0)

        self.snipper = SnippingWidget()
        self.snipper.closed.connect(self.on_closed)
        threading.Thread(target=self.wait_hotkey,args=(),daemon=True).start() # Запуск потока для hotkey
        
    def wait_hotkey(self):
        keyb.add_hotkey("Ctrl + 6", lambda:print(1))  # это работает 
        keyb.add_hotkey("Ctrl + 8", self.activateSnipping) # не работает 
        keyb.wait()    
 
    def activateSnipping(self):
        self.snipper.showFullScreen()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.hide()

    def on_closed(self):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("testpic/testImage.png")
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.show()
        self.adjustSize()

    


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()       
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PIL import ImageGrab
# import threading
import keyboard as keyb


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class KeyBoardManager(QtCore.QObject):
    keySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    
    def start(self):    
        keyb.add_hotkey("Ctrl + 8", self.keySignal.emit, suppress=True)   
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class SnippingWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SnippingWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.outsideSquareColor = "red"
        self.squareThickness = 2

        self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint() 
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start_point = event.pos()
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        r = QtCore.QRect(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        self.hide()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        bbox = r.getCoords()
        if bbox[0] == bbox[2] or bbox[1] == bbox[3]:
            self.show()
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                None, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Не выбран прямоугольник для скриншота, попродуйте еще раз.')
            super().mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent)
            return 
        
#        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=r.getCoords())
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=bbox)
        img.save("temp/testImage.png")                       # <---- установите свой путь      
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        self.closed.emit()
        self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        trans = QtGui.QColor(22, 100, 233)
        r = QtCore.QRectF(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        trans.setAlphaF(0.2)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        outer = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        outer.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()))
        inner = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        inner.addRect(r)
        r_path = outer - inner
        qp.drawPath(r_path)
        qp.setPen(
            QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(self.outsideSquareColor), self.squareThickness)
        )
        trans.setAlphaF(0)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        qp.drawRect(r)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Делать скриншот')
        self.button.setShortcut('Ctrl+7')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.activateSnipping)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 0)

        self.snipper = SnippingWidget()
        self.snipper.closed.connect(self.on_closed)
        
        # Запуск потока для hotkey
#        threading.Thread(target=self.wait_hotkey,args=(),daemon=True).start() 
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        manager = KeyBoardManager(self)                                      # +++
        manager.keySignal.connect(self.wait_hotkey)                          # +++
        manager.start()                                                      # +++
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
    def wait_hotkey(self):
#        keyb.add_hotkey("Ctrl + 6", lambda:print(1))           # это работает 
#        keyb.add_hotkey("Ctrl + 8", self.activateSnipping)     # не работает 
#        keyb.wait()   

# !!! +++
        self.activateSnipping()                                               # !!! +++
 
    def activateSnipping(self):
        self.snipper.showFullScreen()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.hide()

    def on_closed(self):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("temp/testImage.png")             # <---- установите свой путь 
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap) 
        self.show()
        self.adjustSize()

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()       
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]